# what is the significance of unnamed argument list while defining function in c++

Tags: c++, function

I have started to learn c++ and reading thinking in c++ volume 1. I come across a statement that in c++ one can define a function with unnamed argument list. I could not appreciate the significance of it. Please guide.

```
int function(int) {
// definition
}

...
function(1); // function call
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It just means that parameter isn't used in the body of the function.

Comment: In that case why can't it be a void. i.e. int function(void)

Comment: Or just `int function()`. There are two main reasons that I know of: it's a virtual function where this specific implementation doesn't use that parameter, but others do; or it's used for overload resolution (`operator++` is a specific example).